# Google Sheets IF condition to check if multiple values in a column exist in another column

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

I want to check if some names in List1 exist in List2, as part of an IF() condition.
If the names do exist, I want to convert that row to 1, and to 0 if not.

=arrayformula(IF(List1 exist in List2),  ?

Does this work?

Comment: Please include actual sample data and expected results. Also `ARRAYFORMULA` is google-sheets. Please remove Excel from the tags if you not using it.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need something like this:

```
=if(isnumber(match(A1,$D$1:$D$4,0)),1,0)
```

you can then drag down the formula to apply it to every cell in column A.

Explanation:

`match(A1,$D$1:$D,0)` will either return a number that indicates the position that A1 appears in the D range (D1:D) **or** it will #N/A if A1 is not found in the D range. Then you apply an if condition to check if the match formula returned a number or not. If it returned a number (which means there was a match), then it gives 1, otherwise 0 (no match).

Comment: Is it possible to change A1 into a range as well? I'm trying to aggregate the matching process without creating a new column.

Comment: Essentially creating a column WITHIN the equation itself to be acted upon by another part of the equation (like sumproduct)

Comment: This worked with arrayformula and matching A:A, D:D.